# Excluding negative numbers based off of two out of several results in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm running a query that results in quantities of both negatives and positives for transactions. I want these to both show for used products; however, I only want to show positives for the deliveries and transfers.

Used, delivery and transfer all are being pulled from the Transaction Type column. I do not know the best method to limit the positives only quantities to just the delivery and transfer transaction types and keep both positives and negatives for used.

I attempted limiting this in the where clause, but that either limited it to pulling strictly deliver and transfers only OR pulling only positives for all transaction types.

In the code below, it shows a case statement that I attempted, however, it threw an error when attempting to run the script.

```
SELECT distinct 
  case when NOT upper(transaction_type) = 'PURCHASE' 
            AND DST_PROPERTY_TYPE = 'WAREHOUSE' THEN 'Return' 
       ELSE transaction_type END transaction_type
  , transaction_type as transaction_type_OG --, division_name2
  , case when transaction_type in ('Delivery','Transfer') 
         then quantity >=0 else quantity end
  , transaction_id
  , comments
  , src_division_name
  , src_property_name
  , src_property_type
  , src_afe, src_rig_name
  , dst_division_id
  , dst_division_name
  , dst_property_name
  , dst_property_type
  , dst_afe
  , dst_rig_name
  , M.CATEGORY_NAME
  , item_id
  , item_name
  , quantity
  , created_by, ticket_number
FROM transactions.tables m
WHERE not CATEGORY_ID IN ('1294','1295','1337') 
  AND MASTER_PROPERTY NOT LIKE '%products%' 
  AND MASTER_PROPERTY NOT LIKE '%TEST%' 
  and transaction_dt = trunc(sysdate) - 1
order by transaction_type, src_property_type, src_property_name
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
with data(trans_type, qty) as (
  select 'Used',-1 from dual union all
  select 'Delivery',-1 from dual union all
  select 'Transfer',-1 from dual union all
  select 'Used',1 from dual union all
  select 'Delivery',1 from dual union all
  select 'Transfer',1 from dual
)
select * from data
where (trans_type = 'Used' or qty > 0);

TRANS_TY        QTY
-------- ----------
Used             -1
Used              1
Delivery          1
Transfer          1
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work, but I tweaked my case statement and was able to get it to pull what I needed.

Thank you for your help, though!

Answer (score 0):

Updated case statement:

```
case when transaction_type in ('Delivery','Transfer') and quantity<0 then 'Duplicate' else transaction_type end TRANSACTION_TYPE_USE
```

I then filtered out the duplicates once this script was added to my crystal report.

Thanks!